# Product attributes not loading in home page. Maybe Permissions? I really don't know

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, indexer, best-seller

I was trying to reboot the index with the `shell/indexer.php` script (because my new categories are not displaying on my megamenu) and after using this script my products are not showing some custom attributes (that I normally show on home, like `unit_weight`). But it's happening only for this 'bestsellers' block:

`{{block type="filterproducts/bestsellers_home_list" category_id="16" name="offer_list" product_count="5" column_count="5" template="filterproducts/grid.phtml"}}`

When I use the 'latest' it works fine:

`{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" name="home_list" product_count="100" column_count="6" template="filterproducts/grid.phtml"}}`

The block's permission is activated. I really don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: Can you please show the code of your blocks:
`filterproducts/bestsellers_home_list`
and `filterproducts/latest_home_list`

Comment: The 2 files that you asked:

https://drive.google.com/a/menu.com.vc/file/d/0B5cv8NWLdE2Qb3ZjY0VXQk5xY0k/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/a/menu.com.vc/file/d/0B5cv8NWLdE2QbVZha0o2Z29fSW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

please check if filterproducts/bestsellers_home_list has allow yes permission 
in admin Panel

> system -> Permission -> Blocks

if no add it and set is allowed Yes.

> Clear cache and check .

wish it could help.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried these things. It doesn't changed anything :(